# Magento/SOAP API needs to delimit street 1 and street 2 in sales order

Tags: api, sales, soap

As per SOAP API need we want's to delimit street into street 1 and street 2 fields for result.

I have override info method of Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Api Class

```
    public function info($orderIncrementId)
    {

        $result = parent::info($orderIncrementId);
        $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

        $streetLines = $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet();
       // unset($result['billing_address']['street']);
        foreach ($streetLines as $i=>$line) {
            $result['billing_address']['address_street'.($i+1)] = $line; 
        }  

        $streetLines1 = $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet();
       // unset($result['shipping_address']['street']);
        foreach ($streetLines1 as $i=>$line) {
            $result['shipping_address']['address_street'.($i+1)] = $line; 
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

And also added below code in wsdl.xml of custom module in local

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions>
    <types>
        <schema> 
              <complexType name="salesOrderAddressEntity">
                <all> 
                     <element name="address_street1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                     <element name="address_street2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
            </schema>
        </types>
</definitions>
```

Also below code in wsi.xml in custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
             targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
        <wsdl:types>
            <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
                  <xsd:complexType name="salesOrderAddressEntity">
                    <xsd:sequence> 
                          <xsd:element name="address_street1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xsd:element name="address_street2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:schema>
        </wsdl:types>
 </wsdl:definitions>
```

Below code in api2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api2>  
      <resources>
            <order translate="title" module="api2">
                <attributes   module="api2">
                  <order_type>Order Type</order_type>
                </attributes>
            </order>
             <order_address translate="title" module="api2">
                <attributes translate=" address_street1 address_street2 "   module="api2"> 
                     <address_street1>Street1</address_street1>
                 <address_street2>Street2</address_street2> 
                </attributes> 
             </order_address>
        </resources>
   </api2>
</config>
```

Is anything else i need to modify to show street as street1 & street2 in result of API method salesOrderInfo?

If I print $result in info(), it is showing street1 & street2 field values in shipping_address and billing_address array, but when I print SOAP API response then it is not displaying it's value.

Comment: I have also created 2 attributes 'address_street1' and 'address_street2' in customer_address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per above description suddenly it is working fine. Now it is showing address_street1 & address_street2 in SalesOrderInfo Soap Api method response.

I think it was Caching issue.

Comment: was there any more to your extension to get this working? I have written up an extension referencing your code above and have successfully rewritten the `sales/order_api` as well as `sales/order_api_v2` models, made sure to include your `*.xml` files, as well as added `street_address1` and `street_address_2` attributes to the `customer_address` entity type and still no luck. Tried blowing out the `var/cache` directory as well as files within the server's `/tmp` directory. Magento will still only include the native attributes for the data returned though.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working! You were indeed correct that it is a caching issue. Just not in the typical location. The server was caching wsdl definitions for sites (shared server) in /tmp. Deleting `/tmp/wsdl-{USER}-*` fixed the issue. ({USER} being the actual user the site runs as, and * being a long jibberish value. There was only one of these files per site that I found).